# Подскажите регулярное выражение (Замена: "/текст<br />" => "<b>текст</b>")

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно регулярное выражение, а лучше непосредственно код (если вас не затруднит) замены:

`/текст<br />`

на

`<b>текст</b>`

Спасибо заранее за помощь!

Answer (score 3):

Както логики в вопросе маловато, ну да ладно.

```
$str = "/текст<br />";

if(preg_match("#\/(.*)<br \/>#", $str))
{
    $str = preg_replace("#\/(.*)<br \/>#", "<b>$1</b>", $str);
}

echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$txt = "/текст<br />";
$txt = str_replace("/","<br>",$txt);
echo($txt);
?>
```

Вот так попробуй
Только лучше вместо / используй например `-b-` или `_b_`